# How to limit the characters of product name on category page?

Tags: product, magento-1.9, theme, category, custom

i have a magento site and my `all products name too long`,that why on `categories page design  has been broken`.I am new in magento,can anybody tell,who  can tell  me,who i will do

Comment: Where on the category page do you want the product name to be limited (truncated?)? In the product list? Everywhere?

Answer (score 4):

goto list.phtml in (yourpackage/yourtemplate/template/catalog/product)

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo substr($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'),0,520) ; ?>
```

Comment: Got error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/nflgeegn/public_html/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 117

Comment: @LuckyDhillon. Try again with the new code. I edited the answer.

Comment: still doesn't work..
nothing changes on the frontend

Answer (score 2):

you can edit your product list file

```
/app/designyourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml


 <?php $prod_name = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                    <?php
                    $count_str = strlen($prod_name);
                    if ($count_str < 50) {
                        echo $prod_name;
                    } else {
                        $offset = 0;
                        $length = 51;   
                        $prod_name = html_entity_decode($prod_name);                     
                        echo htmlentities(mb_substr($prod_name,0,$length,'utf-8')). "...";;                        
                    }
                    ?>
```

if you don't have character encoding issue you can use [php substr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) as well.

hope this will sure help you

Comment: I added the above code in list.phtml
changed the length= 10;
but nothing changed.

Comment: you can use substr function of php.

Comment: you edited correct file ? it should work. its working in my end. And also please change `if` condition as well  if `($count_str < 10) {`

Comment: still doesn't work ..

Comment: you can use like <?php
`echo substr("Hello world",0,4);` will print `hello` for detail see http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp
?>